# error while running rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails

when i try to migrate a single file using rake db:migrate:up VERSION=20121217051908 command error is shown.
'rake' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

then i tried using bundle exec rake db:migrate:up VERSION=20121217051908 again error is shown.

```
WARNING: 'task :t, arg, :needs => [deps]' is deprecated.  Please use 'task :t, [
args] => [deps]' instead.
    at D:/ROR/appmallserver/lib/tasks/download_apk.rake:5:in `block in <top (req
uired)>'
rake aborted!
D:/ROR/appmallserver/lib/tasks/handster.rake:69: invalid multibyte char (US-ASCI
I)
D:/ROR/appmallserver/lib/tasks/handster.rake:69: invalid multibyte char (US-ASCI
I)
D:/ROR/appmallserver/lib/tasks/handster.rake:69: syntax error, unexpected $end,
expecting keyword_then or ';' or '\n'
            unless node.text == "Next ??"
                                        ^
```

(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Comment: You have an invalid multibyte character at `D:/ROR/appmallserver/lib/tasks/handster.rake:69`. Reading error messages is good :)

Comment: i went to the file and the 69th line read as  doc.xpath("//div[@class='bottom-pager']/span[@class='p_pager']/a").each do |node|
            unless node.text == "Next »"

Comment: can u be little more specefic i am new to ror

Comment: can u show the migration file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Ruby is choking on the `»`. Put this at the very top of `handster.rake`:

```
# encoding: utf-8
```